# Understanding jacobian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a function $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2$, then $df_{(x,y,z)}=(2x,2y,-2z)$. Now the statement is if $a\neq 0$ and $f(x,y,z) = a$ then $df_{(x,y,z)}\neq 0$ and I can't understand why $df_{(x,y,z)}\neq 0$.

I was trying to consider a simpler case, say $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and if $f(x,y) = a\neq 0$, then what does it mean geometrically, in the multivariable calculus sense, when we say $df_{(x,y)}\neq 0$ in this case where we have a circle?

A hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for the gradient to be equal to zero is when $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all zero. At that point, $f=0$. Therefore, if $f$ is not zero you can't be at that point, so the gradient must not be zero.

Comment: Ahh yes, silly of me, thanks.